# How to draw the graph in framebuffer using c language..?

Tags: c++, c, linux, framebuffer

i am new to this linux framebuffer so do anybody guide me to draw the line-graph in framebuffer. And i have the code to draw graph in turbo c but now in linux. So please help me out.

Thank You,
Rahul

Answer (score 19):

Use `open()` on the right file in `/dev` (eg. `/dev/fb0`), then use `mmap()` to map it into memory.  Manpages will help for these syscalls if you do not know how to use them.

Then there are some structures and constants for some `ioctl()`s in `<linux/fb.h>`.  Like many kernel headers, you can learn a lot simply browsing the file.

Particularly interesting is the ioctl `FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO` with `struct fb_var_screeninfo`.  Note this has `xres`, `yres` (resolution) and `bits_per_pixel`.  Then there's `FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO` and `struct fb_fix_screeninfo` which has further information like `type` and `line_length`.

So a pixel at (x, y) might be at `mmap_base_address + x * bits_per_pixel/8 + y * line_length`.  The exact format of the pixels will depend on the structures you retrieve via ioctl; it's your job to decide how to read/write them.

It's been a while since I've worked with this so I'm a bit hazy on more details..

Here's a quick and dirty code sample just to illustrate how it's done...  I haven't tested this.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <linux/fb.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   struct fb_var_screeninfo screen_info;
   struct fb_fix_screeninfo fixed_info;
   char *buffer = NULL;
   size_t buflen;
   int fd = -1;
   int r = 1;

   fd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
   if (fd >= 0)
   {
      if (!ioctl(fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &screen_info) &&
          !ioctl(fd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &fixed_info))
      {
         buflen = screen_info.yres_virtual * fixed_info.line_length;
         buffer = mmap(NULL,
                       buflen,
                       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_SHARED,
                       fd,
                       0);
         if (buffer != MAP_FAILED)
         {
            /*
             * TODO: something interesting here.
             * "buffer" now points to screen pixels.
             * Each individual pixel might be at:
             *    buffer + x * screen_info.bits_per_pixel/8
             *           + y * fixed_info.line_length
             * Then you can write pixels at locations such as that.
             */

             r = 0;   /* Indicate success */
         }
         else
         {
            perror("mmap");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         perror("ioctl");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      perror("open");
   }

   /*
    * Clean up
    */
   if (buffer && buffer != MAP_FAILED)
      munmap(buffer, buflen);
   if (fd >= 0)
      close(fd);

   return r;
}
```

Comment: When i compile i am getting some errors like this,
In file included from g.c:4:
/usr/include/sys/mman.h:38: error: conflicting types for ‘mode_t'
/usr/include/linux/types.h:15: error: previous declaration of ‘mode_t' was here
In file included from g.c:5:
/usr/include/unistd.h:203: error: conflicting types for ‘gid_t'
/usr/include/linux/types.h:27: error: previous declaration of ‘gid_t' was here
/usr/include/unistd.h:208: error: conflicting types for ‘uid_t'
/usr/include/linux/types.h:26: error: previous declaration of ‘uid_t' was here
In file included from /usr/include/bits/fcntl.h:25,

Comment: @Rahul - Must be the order I put the headers in...  Maybe try sys/types.h first?

Comment: I added the sys/types.h header line but the new errors haven been appeared like,
/usr/include/sys/mman.h:38: error: conflicting types for ‘mode_t'
/usr/include/linux/types.h:15: error: previous declaration of ‘mode_t' was here

Comment: I don't know what to say.  I would play with the order of includes.  Maybe unistd should go earlier?  Everything compiles OK here.

Comment: Otherwise maybe copy linux/fb.h locally and fix it not to include linux/types.  (hackish, but your headers seem like they might be broken.)

Comment: Send me whole program. In that i can see the values how you assigned for 'x' and 'y' using buffer..?

Comment: I'm not getting compile errors, but when I try to run it (both in X11 and tty1), nothing appears. Nothing is drawn to the framebuffer.

Comment: @B1KMusic - The code I have here does only device setup, it doesn't do any writes.  Did you try filling in stuff at the "TODO" part?

Comment: @asveikau Ah, I was thinking that. And nope. Since I couldn't seem to find any documentation on the framebuffer aside from `/usr/include/linux/fb.h`, I went to plan B: scour the internet for at least one working demo that I could mess with to gain a hands-on experience with it. I did end up finding one, however, and now I have a much better understanding of how to write to the device. Not to mention, I don't have nearly as much experience in C as I do in JavaScript, so I'm still learning a lot of things. From what I've experienced so far, though, it's a beautiful language.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to [asveikau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830836/how-to-draw-the-graph-in-framebuffer-using-c-language/1830865#1830865), you could use [DirectFB](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328110009/http://www.directfb.net/), which may greatly simplify things for you.

Comment: DirectFB also has marvelous things such as hardware specific code for drawing lines and copying rectangles.

Comment: But how that DFB can be accessed

Comment: I don't want to create problems, but DirectFB is a sex website, not a FB API.

Comment: @AlessandroMascolo It apparently moved. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

From my Synaptic on Rasbian: "DirectFB is a graphics library which was designed with embedded systems in mind. It offers maximum hardware accelerated performance at a minimum of resource usage and overhead."

Anyway, I haven't seen this work in a frame buffer yet but I'm hoping it's like I do most of my graphics.  You have some linear address space, height * width * bytes per pixel number of bytes.  If you want to write to a particular x,y location, the position in that space is given by (y * width * bytes per pixel) + (x * 3).  Colors are adjacent bytes RGB (usually) so that gets you the address of the red pixel, add 1 for green, 2 for blue.  You malloc(height * width * bytes per pixel) an address space, write into it, then pick your choice of libpng, libjpeg, libtiff to write that buffer out to a file.  If you want to put text in it too you have to roll your own, so I stole one from an old libgif.  I've reached the age and experience level where it's easier to do it myself than learn how somebody else thought it should be done.  My graphics come out like this:
[image: data taken as CSV from rtl_power]

I've been trying to use a framebuffer as described at http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.com/2014/04/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi.html but something is wrong.  I'm on a Pi 3, it was probably written for a Pi 1 since it was 2014, not 2017 then.  But the Pi is different than traditional framebuffers because the GPU runs the show.  Use this method: http://elinux.org/RPi_Framebuffer

Comment: Alan, interesting looking graph `:)`. It is unclear whether you are providing an answer to the original question, or a new question in the form of the answer. (I read it as a bit of both...) If your intent is to get help with your issue, then it is better to ask a new question, as the questions in your answer here are unlikely to prompt any further answer. Additionally, since it is RaspberryPi related, your best bet is probably to post on [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Best of luck either way.

Comment: I've yet to actually use a framebuffer since OpenBSD doesn't have them and that's mostly what I've run for 15 years.  Not looking for help, just explaining graphics without libraries.  I'm about to give libvnc a try since it gives a virtual framebuffer you can connect to with a vnc client, and it runs in a window instead of taking over the whole display.  I'm trying to do SDR with a waterfall so I need graphics that move, not just still images.

Comment: VNC is essentially remote framebuffer, that's what gave me the idea: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=189032 (my thread there)

Comment: Yes, it seems to work exactly as I expected.  I wrote a loop sending 900 bytes to the virtual framebuffer and it drew a line as I expected.  I connected from another machine to see it, it was on a Raspberry Pi, I was on an i386 OpenBSD box.  Bad documentation took me the longest time, the argc and argv in the demos do nothing at all, they're just placeholders.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I'm glad you have it working. I have a Pi3 that I generally interface with via ssh, but I'm intrigued by your results. (I'm actually amazed at what they crammed into the Pi3, and how well Debian runs on it) Using the vnc framebuffer in place of the hardware. Probably more forgiving as well. As long as you have the correct address for the virtual framebuffer -- I guess the worst case is crashing vnc instead of taking the box down.